# function output from select

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-brown-i33oo)

```
   <script>
      let g;
      function aaa() {
        var dnd = document.querySelector("#colors");
        g = dnd.value;
      }
      console.log(g);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="tema" id="colors" onchange="aaa()">
      <option value="">theme</option>
      <option value="green">green</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
      
    </select>
    </body>
```

I want to output my choosed option out  of my function, how can I do that?... I try

```
    <script>
      let g;
      function aaa() {
        var dnd = document.querySelector("#colors");
        g = dnd.value;
      }
      console.log(g);
    </script>
```

But it dosen't work, please help me to resolve this

Comment: `g` will have value when your function will get called else it will give you undefined.

Comment: yes I see that, how can I fixed that?

Answer (score 2):

To fix your immediate issue move the `console.log()` line *inside* the function you call:

```
var g;

function aaa() {
  var dnd = document.querySelector("#colors");
  g = dnd.value;
  console.log(g);
}
```

*However* there's some additional improvements you can make to the code.

Firstly, remove the `g` global variable. Declare it locally to the function instead. The value of the `select` can be read from the DOM in other functions if necessary.

Secondly, use an unobtrusive event handler. `onchange` and the other `onX` attributes are no longer good practice and should be avoided. Use `addEventListener()` instead.

```js
document.querySelector("#colors").addEventListener('change', e => {
  let g = e.target.value;
  console.log(g);
})
```

```html
<select name="tema" id="colors">
  <option value="">theme</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
</select>
```